# How can we use both Hamming distance and distance between coordinates to match features?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, hamming-distance, video-tracking

As known, for tracking objects in OpenCV we can use:

- [FeatureDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=surffeaturedetector#featuredetector) to find features
- [DescriptorMatcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher) to match similarity between features of the desired object and features of current frame in video
- and then use [findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography) to find the new position of the object

For matching features [DescriptorMatcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher) uses Hamming distance (value of the difference between the two sequences of the same size, not the distance between coordinates).

I.e. we find the most similar object in the current frame, but not the most nearest to the previous position (if we know it).

How can we use to match both Hamming distance and distance between coordinates, for example, given the weight of both, not only Hamming distance?

It could solve the following problems:

- If we start to track object from position (x,y) on previous frame, and the current frame contains two similar objects, then we will find the most similar, but not the most nearest. But due to inertia coordinates usually changes slower than similarity (a sharp change in light or rotation of the object). And we must to find the similar object with the nearest coordinates.
- Thus we find the features, which not only the most similar, but which will give the most accurate homography, because we exclude features, which, although very similar, but are very far away in coordinates and most likely belong to other objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is probably something like:

1. Compute matches as usual.
2. `DMatch` has `queryIdx` and `trainIdx` indices. You can use these to retrieve the corresponding keypoints. Compute the euclidean distance between them, and update the value `distance` if `DMatch` with some kind of weighting function.
3. Sort matches by distance (since `distance` has changed).

Now the matches vector is sorted according both hamming distance between descriptors and euclidean distance between keypoints.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no build-in method in opencv to do that.

What I'd do is to use the cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatch. It finds all the matches that are under a certain Hamming distance. You'd need to find a radius/distance that ensures that the features are similar enough for your application, but not too big to make the whole calculation slow.

Then, from this features you can choose the one that's closest to the position you predicted the feature would be, or calculate some kind of weighted score based on Hamming distance and cordinate distance, etc.